# The parent node "container" has height ,margin can be calculated,Why "item" css margin-top and margin-bottom has no effect,?

Tags: css, margin, vertical-alignment

[image]

The parent node "container" has height ,margin can be calculated,Why "item" css margin-top and margin-bottom has no effect?

```css
body,html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 10px 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item  {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want margin to inherit from parent? or align center vertically

Comment: i hope the item align center and vertically。@YuvarajM